# django one-to-many relation

Tags: python, django

In my app,I need to associate the `User` with a `user-selected-filename`

A user can only select one filename.But the same filename may be selected by many users

So,database table may be like this

## auth_user(created by `django.contrib.auth`)

```
-----------------------------------------
id | username | first_name | last_name | ...
------------------------------------------
1  |  bert     |  bert     | russel    |...
------------------------------------------
2  |  jon      |  jon      | snow      | ...
-------------------------------------------
3  |  alice    | alice     | tanner    | ...
```

## userfile table

```
-----------------------------------------------
id  | filename              
------------------------------------------------
1   |  '/clips/summary.mp4'  
------------------------------------------------
2   | '/clips/intro.mp4'    
------------------------------------------------
```

## user_userfile table

```
-----------------------------------
 user_id   |    userfile_id
-----------------------------------
   1       |    1
-----------------------------------
   2       |    1
-----------------------------------
   3       |    2
-----------------------------------
```

It seems that `userfile--user` is a `1 - n` relation . 1 userfile can be associated with many users.

So,what should I use to represent this relationship?
In class UserFile given below ,if I use

```
user = db.models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.User)
```

That will only make the reverse relationship (ie `n-1` for `userfile--user`)

```
class UserFile(db.models.Model):
    filename = db.models.CharField()
    user     = ??
```

Comment: The way of creating a `1-N` relation in Django is by using a Foreign key. In this case I would create a foreing key in `User` model. I don't see any problem.

Comment: @DiegoNavarro **Never** modify the code of django. Unless you're sure they will accept your patches: which is definitively not the case here since it's project-specific.

Comment: I'm not talking about modify any Django code, only answering the relation problem. In that case you should subclass that or create a middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really like a OneToMany field too. But the reason there is no such field in Django i believe is that this would create an FK on the table of the related model:

1. That's sort of confusing
2. Syncdb wouldn't be able to add the column to the existing table

The solution to add the FK on a related model is to use an "unsupported" feature:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
models.ForeignKey(Badge, null=True, blank=True).contribute_to_class(User, 'badge')
```

Then you should add [migrate auth_user](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/20833599582/django-schema-migrations-nashvegas-vs-south-vs) to add the FK.

Comment: thanks for the reply..I couldn't find any references to `contribute_to_class` on djangoproject site..why is this termed unsupported?

Comment: Because it's not documented, so it's not part of the "public API". It is subject to undocumented potential BC breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use userprofiles for this, although I suppose it would be a bit overkill.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(UserFile)
```

Then set the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting in settings.py and run syncdb.

Now you can use `user.get_profile().file` to access the file associated with `user`.

[Tutorial on userprofiles](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile)